# Analyzing syntax: "Cui viro divinum quiddam inesse existimabatur, adeo ut putaretur etiam cum numinibus habere sermonem."

Tags: syntax

everyone. Here is the sentence and my thoughts about it:

Cui viro divinum quiddam inesse existimabatur, adeo ut putaretur etiam cum numinibus habere sermonem.

First of all, I am curious about the first clause, namely "Cui viro divinum quiddam inesse existimabatur". Is this clause a nominative and infinitive construction (Nominativus cum infinitivo)? Secondly, I wonder whether "inesse" is a verb here or an direct object. I think it is a verb. Thirdly, I  wonder what to categorise "habere sermonem" as. Are these words one direct object or two direct objects?

Comment: I've edited the title so that it lets people see something less generic about the question. Please edit the question to tell us the source of the sentence.

Answer (score 7):

Let's see:

**Is the first clause a Nominativus cum Infinitivo?**

Yes, the nominative being *divinum quiddam* – “something divine” – and the infinitive being *inesse* – “to be in.”

**How to categorize *habere sermonem*?**

The subordinate clause introduced by *adeo ut* also looks like an NcI, except that the subject is just implied: *hic vir putaretur habere ⋯* Thus, *habere* is the verb of the indirect speech, just like *inesse* in the first clause, and *sermonem* is its direct object. *Sermonem habere* = “to talk, to be in conversation.”

(Alternatively, I guess *putaretur* can be viewed as an impersonal passive (“it was thought”) starting an Accusativus cum Infinitivo construction, as *putare* very regularly does. The subject of the indirect speech would then just be implied: *putaretur hunc virum habere ⋯* I would, however, think that in this case the accusative subject would typically be written out, at least as a little *eum*. Anyway, it makes no significant difference in meaning.)

Comment: I think OP might be asking whether there's a particular term to describe the role of the infinitive in these NcI constructions. I would probably call it a subject complement, treating putaretur as a linking verb.

Comment: You are right, Kingshorsey. Does this mean that "inesse" is also a subject complement?

Comment: @Something71 *Inesse* is the predicate of the subordinate clause.